# PubNub grant auth key using REST API

Tags: pubnub

What I want is grant a specific auth key with specific chat rooms using the PubNub REST API.
Can that be done?

Comment: Yes, it is. Please review the REST API docs for this: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/pubnub-rest-api-documentation#pubnub-access-manager-pam

Comment: @CraigConover I didn't understand the signature creation part, Could you please tell me how is it done, any links for more details to that?
Thanks.

Comment: here is an example of creating a signature: https://github.com/pubnub/javascript/blob/9a58a46827ff1db3cc511c3d294fd9108170b05f/src/core/components/endpoint.js#L50-L62

Comment: and the hmac256 https://github.com/pubnub/javascript/blob/9a58a46827ff1db3cc511c3d294fd9108170b05f/src/core/components/cryptography/index.js#L36-L39

Comment: @StephenBlum Thank you.

Comment: Did Stephen help you get the answer you needed?

Comment: @StephenBlum please look into it and help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56889108/how-to-implement-pubnub-access-manager-in-swift

Comment: @Ash0ur can I grant using rest API without server/backend? I want to grant in swift language. Any help from your side will be appreciatable.